# Conditional Prebuild Event Commands

Tags: continuous-integration, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, pre-build-event

### Background

Currently I run a pre-build command when building my solution locally. However, this command isn't needed when building on my VSTS Continuous Integration Server.

### Question

Is there a way to only run the pre-build event commands when building on a local machine?

I'm aware you can add conditional statements like below. But is there something to distinguish if its a local build or a CI build?

```
if $(ConfigurationName) ==  Local
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the [Visual Studio build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/visual-studio-build) task in VSTS you can pass MSBuild parameters from the task configuration. This way you can define your own custom property like `RunsOnCI` and default it to `false`. You can then set it to `true` in your build definition.

Assume you have the following code in your pre build event:

```
if $(BuiltOnCI) == true (
    echo "Hello World!"
)
```

You then need to edit your `.csproj` file and add the BuiltOnCI property with a default value:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <BuiltOnCI>false</BuiltOnCI>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can test your changes by running MSBuild on the command line. Running it like this will not show the Hello World message:

```
msbuild myproject.csproj
```

Passing the parameter on the command line allows you to set it to true:

```
msbuild StackoverflowSample.csproj /p:BuiltOnCi=true
```

Now that it works locally, you can use `/p:BuiltOnCi=true` and put in your VSTS task in the MSBuild arguments field.

Comment: Would you be able to expand on this a little more. I think I understand the logic, just not where to set all the components. I've appended `/p:BuiltOnCI=true` in my MSBuild Arguments in VSTS and set this condition in my pre-build events in my solution.`if "$(BuiltOnCI)" != true`

Comment: @DanCundy I've updated my post with a sample. Does that work?

Comment: That worked well, thank you. Struggled a little with the pre-build syntax, but got there in the end.